# Django: AttributeError: type object 'Data_Point ' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a migration, but however I am running into an issue. I am getting the error:

```
queryset = Data_Point.objects.all()
AttributeError: type object 'Data_Point' has no attribute 'objects'
```

and I am not sure why. I have googled the error, and still can not find a soultion. Could the error lie in the models.py class? Specifically could the issue be with the association with each table and the foreign keys? Here are the follow classes:

models.py

```
class System(models.Model):
    System = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.System

class Sub_System(models.Model):
    Sub_System = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    System = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Sub_System

class Data_Name(models.Model):
    Data_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Sub_System = models.ForeignKey(Sub_System, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Data_Name

class Data_Point(models.Model):
    Captured_Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    Inserted_Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    Data_Value = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    Data_Name = models.ForeignKey(Data_Name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Data_Value
```

views.py

```
class SystemView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = System.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SystemSerializer

class Sub_SystemView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sub_System.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Sub_SystemSerializer

class Data_NameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Data_Name.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Data_NameSerializer

class Data_PointView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Data_Point.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Data_PointSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class SystemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = System
        fields = ('id', 'System')

class Sub_SystemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sub_System
        fields = ('id', 'Sub_System', 'System')

class Data_NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data_Name
        fields = ('id', 'Data_Name', 'Sub_System')

class Data_Point(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data_Point
        fields = ('id', 'Captured_Timestamp', 'Inserted_Timestamp', 'Data_Value', 'Data_name')
```

Comment: Please *don't* give your serializers the same name as the model, rename `Data_Point` to `DataPointSerializer` at the bottom.

Comment: Of course it was the smallest thing. That did the trick! Thank you so much!